# What is the difference between the Source Port and the StunServerPort

Tags: server, xmpp, stun

I am developing a peer to peer call. I am using `de.javawi.jstun.test` .
I found this constructor in `de.javawi.jstun.test.DiscoveryTest` .

```
public DiscoveryTest(InetAddress sourceIaddress, int sourcePort, String stunServer, int stunServerPort) {
    this.sourceIaddress = sourceIaddress;
    this.sourcePort = sourcePort;
    this.stunServer = stunServer;
    this.stunServerPort = stunServerPort;
}
```

My question is What is the difference between the Source Port and the StunServerPort??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stunServerPort` is the port the STUN server listens on for incoming binding requests.  This is typically one of the standard STUN ports: `3478` or `3479`.

`sourcePort` is the port the client behind a NAT has obtained locally to create a socket with.  Most often, the client attempting to do P2P will ask the OS to randomly pick an available local port to send/receive from.  You can probably pass `0` for sourcePort and let it pick the port for you as well.  Or if you already have a socket, use the same port as your local, and DiscoveryTest will set the reuseaddr flag so it can have a socket co-exist.